# Change size of NgbDatepicker in Angular 4

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

For some reason unknown to me, my NgbDatePicker is much smaller than I want it to be.  It currently displays at the following size:

[image]

...when I was expecting it to display at the size in the example found [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples)

One weird thing that I noticed is that the following portion of the datepicker in my application has the attribute `_ngcontent-c0` set on its div:

[image]

...meanwhile the exact same portion of the example found on the website has the attribute `_ngcontent-c4` set on its div.  *This means that their divs aren't even the same.*  This same attribute is also used in several css selectors.

This is the code in which I make the datepicker appear.  I make it appear when an input field is clicked:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input readonly class="form-control rounded" (click)="d.toggle()" (clickOutside)="onDocumentClick($event, d)" (ngModelChange)="onModelChanged($event)" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
             name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
      <svg><use xlink:href="sprite.svg#calendar"></use></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is the ngOnInit() code of the component that configures the DatePicker:

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
    let today = new Date();
    let todayInDateStruct = {day: today.getUTCDate(), month: today.getUTCMonth() + 1, year: today.getUTCFullYear()};
    this.config.maxDate = this.maxDate || todayInDateStruct;
    this.config.minDate = this.minDate || {year: 1900, month: 1, day: 1};

    if (this.minDate$) {
        Rx.on(this, this.minDate$, (minDate: NgbDateStruct) => {
            if (minDate) {
                this.config.minDate = minDate;
            }
        });
    }

    /*
     The following line sets the first day of the week on the Calendar to Sunday instead of the default Monday.

     source: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api
     */
    this.config.firstDayOfWeek = 7;
    }
```

Is there any way of increasing the size of the NgbDatepicker without overriding several NgbDatepicker styles?

Comment: I think the issue might be caused by something overriding the ngBootstrap's styles (for example by employing some other framework similar to ngBootstrap). If that's the case then you don't need to look for workarounds like resizing the datepicker. I run into exactly the same issue and it turned out I had Semantics UI added directly to the index.html (don't ask - team work :)). This caused my ngbDatepicker to behave as you described.

Answer (score 1):

I think u can use this. 
create a custom template, for example:

```html
<ng-template #tpl let-date="date" let-currentMonth="currentMonth" let-selected="selected">
            <div class="day">{{ date.day }}
            </div>
 </ng-template>
```

then set the dayTemplate property: `[dayTemplate]="tpl"`

and CSS:

```css
.day {      
    text-align: center;
    padding: 7px;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
.ngb-dp-day{
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
  }
.ngb-dp-weekday{
   width: 100% !important;
   height: 100% !important;
}
```

the padding is distance between day and day.
because the default css for dayview and weekday is "width: 2rem, height: 2rem" so you need to modify it by add "!important".

add "**encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None**" into your component

Answer (score -1):

It will work if we use in Global css or sass(In style.css)

Comment: it is bad practice to insert css for components in a global scss file, this might affect the whole application

Comment: explained why answer is not following the best practices